# PHP Use array results to complete MySQL query and add results to existing array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach, where-clause

I solved the problem with both the `foreach` loop stopping after the first iteration, as well as it not writing to the array by adding `true` to the `json_decode`. I was unaware that that changed it from object oriented to associated.

```
include '/var/www/html/api/apitoken.php';
include '/var/www/html/api/secrets.php';

$data = file_get_contents('/var/www/html/api/shOrders.json'); // put the contents of the file into a variable
$shOrders = json_decode($data, true);


$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1",$user,$pass,"api") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());

$a=0;

foreach($shOrders['varID'] AS $varID) {

  $sql_statement= " SELECT invTrack AS invTrack, varID AS varID, varSKU AS varSku, revelSku AS revelSku, revelInvID AS revelInvID, p.prodID AS prodID, pr.ingredient AS ing, pr.main_product AS mainProduct, pr.product AS product, i.invID AS invC, pr.qty AS QTY
                    FROM shopifyProd sp
                    LEFT JOIN product p ON sp.revelSku = p.sku AND p.location = 1
                    LEFT JOIN prodRecipe pr ON p.prodID = pr.main_product
                    LEFT JOIN inventory i ON pr.product = i.prodID
                    WHERE varID =" . $varID . " ;   ";

  //connect to mysql db and process the statement
  $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql_statement);

  //var_dump($sql_statement . "<br><br>");
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "varID: ";
    print_r($row['varID']);
    echo "<br>";
      if($varID == $row['varID']) {
      //set correct invID for product in revel
        if (!$row['invC']) {
          $revInvID = ( (int) $row['revelInvID']);
        }else{
          $revInvID = ( (int) $row['invC']);
        }
      //calculate qty to change in revel
        if(!$row['QTY']) {
          $changeQTY = $shOrders['soldQTY'][$a];
        }else{
          $changeQTY = ($row['QTY'] * $shOrders['soldQTY'][$a]);
        }

        echo $varID . " RESULTS! -- ";
        print_r("varSku: " . $shOrders['varSku'][$a]);
        echo ", ";
        print_r("revelInvID: " . $row['revelInvID']);
        echo ", ";
        print_r("soldQTY: " . $shOrders['soldQTY'][$a]);
        echo ", ";
        print_r("ingredient: " . $row['ing']);
        echo ", ";
        print_r("Product: " . $row['product']);
        echo ", ";
        print_r("invC: " . $revInvID);
        echo ", ";
        print_r("changeQTY: " . $changeQTY);
        echo "<br><br>";


        $shOrders['revProdID'][$a] = ( (int) $row['product']);
        $shOrders['revInvID'][$a] = ( (int) $revInvID);
        $shOrders['changeQTY'][$a] = ( (float) $changeQTY);

        if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql_statement)) {
        print_r(mysqli_error_list($con));
        echo "<br>";
        mysqli_close($con);
        }
      }


    }
    $a++;
  set_time_limit ( 30 );
}


echo "<pre>";
print_r($shOrders);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Ok, I have commented out the variables defining the sub-arrays, and now the page is loading. I have NO IDEA why that would have cause a problem in the php, but I'm at least a step closer.

Comment: You should add error handling in your code, so that you don't get a HTTP 500 error, but a nice error message. As you have updated your question several times now, ask yourself if we should read the first part still. Better make your question short and to the point.

Comment: wall of text, too much text and code no one will read & answer, surely can make it more succinct? Oh half of this is updates ok i understand. Ok well good luck would help but gotta go !!!

Comment: @trincot I have so rarely ever run into a php error like this that I have never thought of using error handling for the php side of things. This is actually the first time I've ever had a page not load where I hadn't just missed a semi-colon or closed off a loop or something quite simple. But thank you, I am looking into it now because it just seems like a generally good idea. I moved the updates to the top, but still feel the original info is important, in case something I've changed was the incorrect way to go.

Comment: The question should not reflect the evolution of your programming endeavors. No-one is interested to see what you did wrong before and fixed in the mean time, so readers then just realize "Oh so I have been wasting my time reading this!? OK, bye". Make your question to the point and only about your question. Update the title so it is about that single question. Remove anything that is not directly related to your current issue. I think many react to this question like I do: "too long, not to the point -- moving on to next question". It really takes some effort to keep people's attention.

Comment: @Andrew I mean no disrespect, as you obviously have a high enough reputation that you actually do help people from time to time, saying my "wall of text" is too much and no one will help me, is exactly the opposite of comments in so many questions I've seen closed, marked vague, or down voted due to lack of information. I didn't repeat myself, I listed the problems I'm facing, and I clearly marked the updates so someone who is generally interested in helping out, knows that I am actively attempting to make this work. But in case my changes further the problems it seems important to add them.

Comment: @ZachDecamp Hi Zach thanks yes didn't mean disrespect either. Just genuinely it can help you solve your own question by trying to minimize the question, and will let people short on time answer quicker, or just understand quicker, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var_dump` out your query just before you run it, Are all the expected parameters there? Try running that in your local db tool (mysql workbench, phpmyadmin), does it do what you like?

`var_dump` out the variables at each step of the way and `die` (or alternatively use a debugger to step through the code 1 line at a time), to see what is happening.

It doesn't look like you've declared `$varID` above the query.

I think you need to move

```
foreach($shOrders->varID AS $varID) {
```

above the `$sql_statement = ...` line.

Comment: Using `var_dump` I was able to see that the loop wasn't actually populating $varID as you suggested. I've never used it before, so thank you for that! I am updating the code to reflect where I am at now. I have adjusted the order as well per your suggestion, and I am now able to get relevant info printing out. Now the only problem id inserting the info back into the existing array. Only way I can figure to work it is by defining a new array and inserting everything into it?

Comment: Honestly, I can't even figure out how to list the info from $shOrders inside the foreach loop. i.e. print out  `$shOrders['soldQTY']` when looping through `foreach($shOrders->varID AS $varID) `

Comment: you're trying to do too much at once. Get one thing working at a time. Try this, right under $shOrders = json_decode($data); put: 
foreach ($shOrders as $data){ var_dump($data);   var_dump($data['soldQTY']); } etc.

Comment: Using your suggestion I still kept getting null results for `$data['soldQTY']`, but I discovered the problem was I was decoding the json file as object oriented instead of associative. After changing that, everything came together quickly.

Comment: Yep when nothing seems to work as expected, it's necessary to go to the top of your script and make sure each line of code does as you expect, and the variables contain what you expect.